# Curved bottom shadow in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css

How add a curl shadow in bootstrap 3 div like this http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects ?

My code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="well index">
        <h1><span class="title">My title</span></h1>
        <p>em ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa </p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></p>
     </div>    
    </div>    

</div>
```

Thaks ;-)

Comment: Just apply the CSS from the link you provided to whatever element you want the shadow to be on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid some unsightly margin-padding issues, I'd put it on the well:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yLDjT/

```
.well:before, .well:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.well:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    right: 20px;
    left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add any of this classes to you div depending of witch effect you prefer.

```
/*==================================================
 * Effect 1
 * ===============================================*/
.effect1{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
            box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 2
 * ===============================================*/
.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 3
 * ===============================================*/
.effect3
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect3:before
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 4
 * ===============================================*/
.effect4
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect4:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
}  

/*==================================================
 * Effect 5
 * ===============================================*/
.effect5
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect5:before, .effect5:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}
.effect5:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 6
 * ===============================================*/
.effect6
{
    position:relative;       
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
            box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.effect6:before, .effect6:after
{
    content:"";
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:50%;
    bottom:0;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
    border-radius:100px / 10px;
} 
.effect6:after
{
    right:10px; 
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
       -moz-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
        -ms-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
         -o-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
            transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 7
 * ===============================================*/
.effect7
{
    position:relative;       
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
            box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.effect7:before, .effect7:after
{
    content:"";
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
    border-radius:100px / 10px;
} 
.effect7:after
{
    right:10px; 
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
       -moz-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
        -ms-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
         -o-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
            transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 8
 * ===============================================*/
.effect8
{
    position:relative;       
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
            box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.effect8:before, .effect8:after
{
    content:"";
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
    border-radius:100px / 10px;
} 
.effect8:after
{
    right:10px; 
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
       -moz-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
        -ms-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
         -o-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
            transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}
```

Comment: good bro, I wanted to embed this in my Ember JS application. Your solution help me out without using external JS out of Ember app.